# Redirect::to_route('admin') redirecting to public folder in laravel 3

Tags: php, redirect, laravel, laravel-3

i made a page in laravel 3 like a year ago and im changing my host, i had problems with Mod_rewrite at making the domain answer to the public folder and i made the public folder the html_public by changing the paths.php file and index.php.

Everithing seems to work fine but when i make a Redirect in the controller i get the url with the public folder for example:

Redirect::to_route('admin');

Takes me to

http://www.Mydomain.com/public/admin

And i need that url witouth the public fonder.

Is there another way to redirect to that route or a easy way to make the redirect without the public folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the config/application.php 
just change the static url or the empty one to the following

which detect the right url for you and for your application function in use like redirect

```
<?php
if (empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) || $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == "artisan") {
$url = 'http://www.mydomain.com';
} else {
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . str_replace('/index.php', '',  $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
 }

return array(

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The URL used to access your application without a trailing slash. The URL
| does not have to be set. If it isn't, we'll try our best to guess the URL
| of your application.
|
*/

'url' => $url,
```

and leave the rest of the file as is it